# What is the difference between "happen to" and "happen about"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Does "happen about" mean "happen to" in this context?

> He also added his voice to those of other European banking leaders calling on the Basel supervisory board, which is meeting twice this month, to clarify what will **happen about** global capital rules as it moves into the next post-credit crisis phase of reforms.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/09/02/europes-lenders-need-mergers-and-a-proper-banking-system-socgen-chairman.html

Comment: happen about {something} = happen *in respect to, in regard to, regarding* {something}; happen to {someone, something} = befall {someone, something}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

happen about {something} = happen in respect to, in regard to, regarding {something};

> I told the landlord about the leaky roof, and asked him what will
>   happen about it. He said he would hire a roofing contractor to fix the leak.
>
> The language of laws which are supposed to govern the behavior of
>   industries is often drafted by lobbyists for those very industries!
>   But little will happen about that, I'm afraid.

happen to {someone, something} = befall {someone, something}.

> He committed a crime.
>   -- What will happen to him?
>   He will go to prison for five years.
>
> The house was ruined in the flood.
>   --What will happen to it?
>   It is beyond repair and will be demolished.
>
> She is in surgery now.
>   --What happened to her?
>   She fell off her bike and her head struck the curb.